# Unable to ignore third party libraries from code coverage report in iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage, slather

Testing an iOS app with Xcode inbuilt Unit test cases which is working fine , enabled code coverage which reports third party library in code coverage report , I want to know how to exclude third party libraries from code coverage report.